# Is there a tokenizer to tokenize Swift language code in python

Tags: python, nlp, data-cleaning, tfidf, tokenization

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var moveOnPath = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 15, height: 15, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .offset(x: -50)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(moveOnPath ? 0 : 360))
                .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 4).repeatCount(10, autoreverses: false))
                .onAppear() {
                    moveOnPath.toggle()
                }
               
        }
        .rotation3DEffect(
            .degrees(70),
            axis: (x: 10, y: 0.5, z: 0.0))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Like for example I have code above available and I would like to tokenize so that only the relevant tokens are extracted such as animation, Animation.linear, duration etc.

Currently I am using:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(document)
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
dense = vectors.todense()
denselist = dense.tolist()
```

It only usese the english language.

Comment: I don't think you mean 'tokenizer', because a tokenizer doesn't select anything, it only determines how to separate the words and returns the full list. Can you give an example of what output you would expect for the example you give?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. So basically it would return only the useful tokens such as "animations", "linear", "stroke" etc and get rid of all the irrelevant info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with NLP, your approach to treat this code as text is unlikely to work imho.

The first thing to do is to properly define the task. You said that you want the system to return "only the relevant tokens such as animation, Animation.linear, duration etc.". So what should be defined as a "relevant token"?

- This is a programming language, so normally the language is finite. Maybe you can prepare a list of all the possible relevant tokens? In this case the task becomes simply about searching the subset of "relevant tokens" contained in the code. Note that you could also have a list of "non-relevant tokens", if more convenient.
- If "relevant" is based on the semantics of the code, the task is much more difficult. Basically you need to design the task similarly to what a human would do: what would be the clues you would use to decide if a token is relevant or not? How to represent these clues as features?